# NullPointerException in java and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

I am writing a login and registration program in java using MySQL.

When I call the register frame from the login frame, the register frame becomes visible but as soon as I click the "register" button after entering information, `NullPointerException` occurs??

The interesting fact is the  `NullPointerException` doesn't occur if I open the register frame directly.

[image]

code is here:

```
    void register() {
         try {
             String query ="insert into darkwebregister (CodeID,Email,Password,Age) values (?,?,?,?)";
             pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
             pst.setString( 1,idtext.getText());
             pst.setString( 2,emailtext.getText());
             pst.setString( 3,passtext.getText());
             pst.setString( 4,agetext.getText());
             pst.execute();
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"YOU ARE REGISTERED SUCESFULLY !!");
             pst.close();
         }catch(SQLException e1) {
             Logger.getLogger(register.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e1);
         }catch(Exception e2) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e2);

         }
    }

    void createConnection() {
         try {
             Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
              con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hackersinfo","root","root");
         }catch(Exception ex) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, ex);
         }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share the NPE stack trace as well.

Comment: Don't post images. Paste your code in here

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at loginform.register.registernow(register.java:186)
 at loginform.register$2.actionPerformed(register.java:126)
 at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
 at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
 at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)

Comment: What is in the line 186 of your file register.java ?

Comment: Also, where is line 126? That is where the ActionPerfomed handler is located.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)